# Xmldiff tool to output node name and previous value

Tags: c#, xml

I am comparing 2 xml files using xml diff dll.
I am unable to get the node name and the old value of the node like for example
file 1 :

***File 1***

```
<LastNameInfo>
    <LNameNum>1</LNameNum>
</LastNameInfo>
```

***File 2 :***

```
<LastNameInfo>
    <LNameNum> 5</LNameNum>
</LastNameInfo>
```

I even need to out put the node name in this example LnameNum and also the old value 1 can some one help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the way the XMLDiff 'diffgram' defines the differences is not based on 'name' but on node order, it enumerates them from the top down.

Take a look at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302295(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more details

You can use the diffpatch tool to apply a diffgram to a particular XML, but also it does not mention explicitly the 'old' value in the diffgram. Its either a change to 'newvalue', or a remove node x, without specifying the contents.

It has the ability to output a HTML view that shows the old and new side by side with color highlighting- but if you are interested in doing something like producing a file that looks like this:

```
<LastNameInfo>
  <LNameNum>
    <old>1</old>
    <new>5</new>
  </LNameNum>
</LastNameInfo>
```

Or even just some console output like:

```
Node Name: LNameNum
Changed From: 1 To: 5
```

You are going to need to parse the XML Diffgram yourself along with your own file and basically find out that

```
 <xd:node match="1">
       <xd:change match="1"/>5</xd:change>
 </xd:node>
```

Is referring to the node named LNameNum

Comment: can u explain me "It has the ability to output a HTML view that shows the old and new side by side with color highlighting".. is there already a tool or code which does this??

Comment: Sure, if you just want to see it in action download XMLNotepad (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7973). The libraries that are being called on are called xmldiffpatch.dll and xmldiffpatch.view.dll

Comment: Oh, should have mentioned in XMLNotepad go to View-> Compare XML Files after you have loaded the first file in the notepad

Comment: Do u know if i can download the source code.. i wanted to do the almost same thing for my project.. but this compare and highlight would be my layer 2..

Comment: http://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/ for XMLNotepad's sourcecode, the xmldiff dlls can be found in the above mentioned MSDN

Comment: i cant see a source code download anywhere :(:( can u help :(.. sorry for too many questions

Comment: for codeplex it looks like a tab called 'source code', pick the latest one and hit download. For the MSDN its the very top of the page, right after the summary section, a word 'here' is highlighted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7822/discussion-between-helpme-and-xeno)